# Get message body using JavaScript API for Office

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, javascript-api-for-office

I'm working on a simple mail app and I need to get the body of a message. **[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn482507.aspx)** says, version **1.1** of **JavaScript API for Office** has `body` property for `message` object and it can be get like this:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.body;
```

but the problem is that I need to access the `body` in `read mode` and MSDN states that:

> **Read mode:** The body property is undefined.

Why is the `body` property `undefined` in `read mode` and How can I access it? *(if possible)*

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same issue.

Comment: @SamStainsby: sadly, no.

Comment: @SamStainsby and SyedAliTaqi it is depend on minimum mailbox requirement in manifest file .[Link](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/1.3/Body.html) otherwise you have to use ews request.

Comment: @InfoÁsith In https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/1.3/Office.context.mailbox.item.html is lists the 'body' member as "Minimum mailbox requirement set version 1.1", which we do specify in the manifest. Is that not sufficient?

Comment: @SamStainsby yes not sufficient .if you carefully see, **getAsync()** ,and **setAsync()** functions are not appeared in requirement set version 1.1. this Body property only support few methods when  requirement set version is 1.1

Comment: @InfoÁsith Yes, but item.body is undefined ... not just missing the getAsync method.

Answer (score 3):

`message.body` or `Office.context.mailbox.item.body` returns [Body](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.item.html#body) type. Try to use this to get body text.

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync('text', function (async) {console.log(async.value)});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is getBody function. it has used CoercionType type

```
function getBody() {
        var _item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
        var body = _item.body;

        // Get the body asynchronous as text
        body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Html, function (asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                // TODO: Handle error
            }
            else {
                // Show data

                console.log('Body', asyncResult.value.trim());
            }
        });
    }
```

but above function is part of mailbox requirement set 1.3. 
however this function will not work in outlook mac because it minimum mailbox requirement is 1.1